# Is it possible to use pandas.DataFrame.rolling window period 5 with skipping today's value in that

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

[need to get output in column <5_Days_Up> like the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ca1dq.png)

```
Date        price       5_Days_Up
20-May-21       1       
21-May-21       2       
22-May-21       4       
23-May-21       5       
24-May-21       6       5
25-May-21       7       6
26-May-21       8       7
27-May-21       9       8
28-May-21       10      9
29-May-21       11      10
30-May-21       12      11
31-May-21       13      12
1-Jun-21        14      13
2-Jun-21        15      14
```

[But, got the output like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmH8l.png)

```
Date        price       5_Days_Up
20-May-21       1       
21-May-21       2       
22-May-21       4       
23-May-21       5       
24-May-21       6       6
25-May-21       7       7
26-May-21       8       8
27-May-21       9       9
28-May-21       10      10
29-May-21       11      11
30-May-21       12      12
31-May-21       13      13
1-Jun-21        14      14
2-Jun-21        15      15
```

Here, in python pandas, I am using

```
df['5_Days_Up'] = df['price'].rolling(window=5).max()
```

is there a way to get the maximum value of the last 5 periods after skipping the today's price using the same rolling()  or any other?

Answer (score 1):

Your data has only 4 (instead of 5) previous entries before the entry on date `24-May-21` with `price` equals `6` (owing to there is no `price` equals `3` in the data sample.) Therefore, your first entry to show non-NaN value will start from the date `25-May-21` with `price` equals `7`.

To include up to the previous entry (exclude current entry), you can use the parameter `closed='left'` to achieve this:

```
df['5_Days_Up'] = df['price'].rolling(window=5, closed='left').max()
```

Result:

```
         Date  price  5_Days_Up
0   20-May-21      1        NaN
1   21-May-21      2        NaN
2   22-May-21      4        NaN
3   23-May-21      5        NaN
4   24-May-21      6        NaN
5   25-May-21      7        6.0
6   26-May-21      8        7.0
7   27-May-21      9        8.0
8   28-May-21     10        9.0
9   29-May-21     11       10.0
10  30-May-21     12       11.0
11  31-May-21     13       12.0
12   1-Jun-21     14       13.0
13   2-Jun-21     15       14.0
```